# Run the Vendor Commands in the Linux Kernel space driver for USB

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, driver, vendor

I am writing a kernel mode usb driver for Linux.

I have a hardware which contains switches, LEDs, bargraph LEDs, bulk data transfers etc. In its specs it explains that you can query to firmware to read state of the individual hardware on a board. They have provided something called Vendor Commands. I cannot figure out that how to send the vendor command using linux kernel USB interface. For some of the individual HW like LEDs and bargraph, there is only one way to know the state by using the Vendor Command. No endpoint info available for that. Using `lsusb -v` command, it just shows 3 endpoints. One Interrupt and 2 Bulk. Interrupt is for one set of switches.

It describes the vendor commands for Interrupt endpoint also.

How to send those command?

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the vendor command documentation a secret.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am basically trying to write a linux port for OSR USB-FX2 for learning purpose. The link to the spec is <http://www.osronline.com/hardware/OSRFX2_32.pdf> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the vendor-specific commands of the OSR USB FX-2 must be sent as control transactions to endpoint 0.

Comment: Only control transfers have a request value.

Comment: Thanks... I am planning to use the function usb_control_msg(). What will be the values of requesttype, value and index fields when I use control urb? I assume that data field will be filled by the device.

Comment: Unused fields are probably zero. But the request type must be a combination of the appropriate `USB_DIR`/`TYPE`/`RECIP` flags.